# onSubmitEditing not functional on android React-native

Tags: react-native, redux-form, textinput

I'm using redux-form and have the following code:

```
<Field name='email' placeholder='abc@gmail.com' title='Email'
 keyboardType={'email-address'} autoFocus={false} component={reduxFormTextInput}
 onSubmitEditing={() => this.moveFocus()}/>
```

reduxFormInput is just a FormInput component from react-native-elements.

The moveFocus function is a console statement:

```
  moveFocus () {
    console.log('ZZZZZZZ')
  }
```

however on hitting the return key on a textInput the only thing that happens is that keyboard closes. no console Statement is executed.

Answer (score 0):

The first click of yours is taken for the keyboard to close,so make the keyboard persist.

Put the

```
 keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"
```

in your Content tag

```
<Content Style={{
                  paddingBottom:0,
                  backgroundColor: 'white'
                }}
                keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always">

    </Content>
```

Now the keyboard will persist and the console statement will get executed.